# Measuring CPU usage

Tags: java, profiling, cpu, cpu-usage

I need help in finding how much of a CPU capacity out of its all power(NOT time) is consumed in percentage of each different method NOT for whole application. For instance MethodA consumed 5% of the CPU power when it is called. Is there Any way to find what I need using coding, library or a tool? Someone has an idea?

The ArrayListCollection class.

```
package collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;


public class ArrayListCollection<T> extends MyCollections {

    public ArrayListCollection() {
        super.collection = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void add(int seed, int number) {
        try {
            random = new Random(seed); 
            int i = 0;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (i < number){
                collection.add(random.nextInt());
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    
     public void remove(int seed, int number) {
        try {
            random = new Random(seed);
            int i = 0;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (i < number){
                collection.remove(random.nextInt());
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void contains(int seed, int number) {
        try {
            int secondSeed = seed + 100;
            ArrayList list = arrayList(seed, secondSeed, number);
            int i = 0;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (i < number){
                collection.contains(list.get(i));
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
 
}
```

The main

```
    
package collections;

import java.util.Random;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      
        int number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int seed = 200;
        
        ArrayListCollection arrayList = new ArrayListCollection();
        
       //ArrayList collection Add
        System.out.print("Add " + number + " elemrnt(S) to ArrayList .... ");
        arrayList.add(seed,number);
        System.out.print(" Done .... ");
        System.out.println("The estimated Time: " + arrayList.estimatedTotalTime() + "\n");       
         
          //ArrayList collection Contains
        System.out.print("Search " + number + " elemrnt(S) in ArrayList .... ");
        arrayList.contains(seed, number);
        System.out.print(" Done .... ");
        System.out.println("The estimated Time: " + arrayList.estimatedTotalTime() + "\n");
         
         //ArrayList collection Remove
        System.out.print("Remove " + number + " elemrnt(S) from ArrayList .... ");
        arrayList.remove(seed, number);
        System.out.print(" Done .... ");
        System.out.println("The estimated Time: " + arrayList.estimatedTotalTime() + "\n");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "CPU capacity".

Comment: The max amount of work can be handled by a CPU which consumes 100% of its power capacity

Comment: When you say "CPU power", do you mean Watts, how hot it makes the CPU, as a fraction of its rated [TDP (Thermal design power)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power)?  Or do you mean how close it comes to maxing out the CPU's instruction throughput or memory bandwidth or other execution resources?  Like how much it would compete with another thread on a logical core sharing the same physical core?  (i.e. how "friendly" it is to the other hyper-thread).  Or something else.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a difference between elapsed times and CPU times, because the scheduler may choose to not run the thread all the time, depending on how many cores are available and how may threads want to run.

Measuring CPU times is not possible in pure Java code. There are profilers that ask the operating system for the actual CPU time that was used on a thread and then scale the measured elapsed times accordingly.

For example, you can do this with [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html):

[image]

The times in the call tree will then show CPU times. This is not exact for short-running methods, because the granularity of the CPU time information is quite large and depends on the operating system.

[image]

The thread monitor shows the total CPU times for those threads were this information could be obtained.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Comment: I will explain in easier way to understand what I need. I need to know each method how much of the CPU processing power is consumed in percentage. If you see task manager and click performance tab on windows it shows how much CPU is currently used in percentage. I need same but for methods. I tried different profilers but they show CPU utilization percentage in a period of time on graph for the whole application but not for each method. Instead it gives me the percentages of time for each method out of the total execution time. I need to get the percentage of the CPU processing power consumed

Comment: That's what the "Hot spots" view in the "CPU view" section of JProfiler will show you, it is an inverted call tree with the methods at the top.